# jQuery class selector not working in IE6/7?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having a problem with jQuery 1.5.1 (can't upgrade, too late in our dev cycle) and class selectors in IE6 and 7.

I have a div on a page, to which I use Javascript to create another div and insert it into the existing div.  The created div is given a class of `my-class-name`.  There's no styling for the class, its just serving as a generic "marker" class.

When I use this selector, it always comes back empty:  `$('.my-class-name').length // always zero.`

It works fine in IE8+, and in all the other browsers. Any ideas?

EDIT:
This is similar to my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var i = 0;

      function addContent() {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'newdiv-' + i);
        newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'my-class');

        var nc = $('#NewContent');
        nc.append(newDiv);

        i += 1;
      }

      function showContentCount() {
        alert($('.my-class').length);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <input type="button" onclick="javascript:addContent();" value="Add new content" />
      <input type="button" onclick="javascript:showContentCount();" value="Show new content count" />
      <div id="NewContent"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

IE8+ works fine, it's only 6 and 7 giving me problems.

Comment: Is it giving an error or just always coming back 0

Comment: Can you provide us with more code? Perhaps a working test-case using http://jsbin.com?

Comment: @slandau:  No errors.  Its just the collection is always coming back empty (no matches).

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: I'll try to put together a small sample.

Comment: Are you sure you are executing it when the DOM is ready?

Comment: It seems like DOCTYPE would be important in this situation. What's your DOCTYPE?

Comment: IE is made to access elements by ID, and nothing else. Try using $('.my-class-name').each(function () { alert('hello'); }) - and see if it's finding your elements, just slowly

Comment: The DOCTYPE is Html 4.01 Strict.

Comment: @BoltClock, IE is optimized to access DOM elements by their ID, nothing else. Other things will work, but that's not how IE was built.

Comment: Just curious, why don't you use jQuery to create the element and set its `id` and `class` attributes as well.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo:  I figured out the problem, but that probably would have saved me some grief.  We're converting a WebForms app to MVC though, so while we've been trying to cleanup where we can, JS is mostly coming over as is for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  The reason is that IE6/7 don't use `class` for the class attribute.  They use `className` instead.  So the line `newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'my-class');` doesn't have the desired effect, instead it has to be `newDiv.setAttribute('className', 'my-class');`.  I put in some logic to account for this, and everything functions as expected now.

Comment: jQuery already knows how to deal with this if you were using its facilities -- you could do `$(newDiv).attr('class', 'my-class')` or `$(newDiv).addClass('my-class')` or even do the whole thing as `$('<div/>', {'class':'my-class', id: 'newdiv-' + i).appendTo($('#NewContent'))`.

Comment: If the creation of this div were as simple as my repo, I would do that.  I am going to put a note to change this in the next version to use jQuery to create as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There is some reason yet undiscovered.  Try to debug with:

```
alert ( $('.my-class-name').length );
var mylen =  $('.my-class-name').length;
alert(mylen);
var mynewLen = $('.my-class-name').size();
alert(mynewLen);
```

`.size()` is a jQuery alias for `.length`

Which version of jQuery? What else is on the page?

NOTE: IF this is on dynamically created elements, this will have to run AFTER the elements are in the DOM.

EDIT: Note to try this

```
$('div.my-class-name').length;
```

Note: class selectors in some jQuery versions will not work properly in some contexts - such as when VML elements are on a page (see jQuery bug #7071).  I am totally shooting in the dark here though.  Workaround: take out .live() on the page, upgrade to jQuery version 1.6.1+ and use .delegate() instead of .live();

Comment: I've updated my question with a sample.  Its jQuery 1.5.1, and its too late in our dev cycle to upgrade.